# Fatal Exception Incompatible Class Change Error | DrawScope Crash

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, android-jetpack-compose, draw

I received this crashlytics crash event, especially by Amazon devices.

Fatal Exception: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
Found interface androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope, but class was expected (declaration of 'androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope' appears in /data/app/~~dI2D-_x33YVzjrNGowkPgw==/com.m128kb.~~~~~-WnvHnaVmpCa58IEaXGiQAw==/base.apk)

**I'm using the latest version of Android Studio and I tried many different JDK versions but it does not work for me. Any Help Guys**

**build.gradle project**

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.2'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }

}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle app**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
}

android {

    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.m128kb."
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 19
        versionName "4.0.2"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }

    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility "1.8"
        targetCompatibility "1.8"
    }
    kotlinOptions {

        freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjvm-default=all-compatibility']
        jvmTarget = "1.8"

    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.3.2"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
    namespace 'com.m128kb.'


}

dependencies {

    def composeBom = platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.12.00')
    implementation composeBom
    androidTestImplementation composeBom

    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    //LiveData
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata'
    // Android Studio Preview support
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    //Icon
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended'
    //Fonts
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-text-google-fonts'


    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.4.0'


    // UI Tests
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
    //Testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'


    //Coroutine
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'

    //Coil
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2"


    def nav_version = "2.5.3"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"

    implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:0.28.0'

    //Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx'


    implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.28.0")


    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"

    //ViewModel
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.5.1")

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

    // define a BOM and its version
    implementation(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.10.0"))
    // define any required OkHttp artifacts without version
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor")

    //lottie
    def lottieVersion = "5.2.0"
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie-compose:$lottieVersion"


}
```

Comment: Try clearing your gradle caches. Or some other caches. This is typically a caching issue.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to delete the whole contents of .gradle folder? @BrianYencho

Comment: No, I wouldn't do that. I would start with the `Invalidate Caches` option in Android Studio. If that doesn't work, try doing `./gradlew cleanBuildCache` and `./gradlew clean` in your project. You only want to resort to manually deleting any folders as a last resort and even still you wouldn't delete the whole `.gradle` folder. You can see more discussions of what you can delete in articles like https://engineering.backmarket.com/put-your-android-studio-on-a-diet-fa4d364acb05

Comment: Hope it works out for you!

Comment: How's this going? Make any progress?

Comment: Yeah, It seems to be working. I unrolled the new update from the amazon app console and uploaded the new version after I cleared the cache as you said. @BrianYencho

Comment: OK hopefully things work out. I took a look again, though, and now I'm wondering if this is actually related to a real issue in Compose itself. This looks similar to https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/1201 and https://forum.intercom.com/s/question/0D55c00006dIgHoCAK/fatal-exception-on-showing-intercom-in-1403-androidx-compose-ui-framework. It seems there might be some issue with a specific Compose version. What is the actual version of Compose you are using?

Comment: Also these: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237071892 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236299800

Comment: It happened with all versions from 1.1.1 - 1.3.2 -@BrianYencho

Comment: Interesting, good to know. There's got to be some dependency conflicts going on here. In the case of https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236299800 there was some conflict with a plugin it seems.

Comment: It's happening to me as well, I can only see reports of this crash in Firebase. However, I am not using AppLovin SDK, so it's definitely something from Compose. Is anyone still encountering this?

Comment: I'm still having this issue even with Compose 1.5.0. I created a new issue (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/319822814), and it seems many developers have already complained about this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, it turns out the problem for us was with our `Applovin Quality Service` plugin, but specifically the version of `com.applovin.quality:AppLovinQualityServiceGradlePlugin` in our `dependencies` list.

First we removed the plugin, and then made an issue with Applovin about it: https://github.com/AppLovin/AppLovin-MAX-Ad-Review-SDK-Android/issues/1

After making the issue i realized our plugin version was out of date, and  upgrade from version `4.3.7` to the latest `4.9.3` and the issue was resolved from this.

I know you're not using the plugin here (from the looks of your gradle file), but i'd try updating any dependencies and plugins you have to see if it fixes the issue.

Posting this here in case anyone else hit the same problem.